# Опциональная типизация в python: проблемы с импортами

Tags: python, python-3.x, архитектура, python-3.5

Пишу на python 3.5, пробую пользовать типизацию, но столкнулся с проблемой циклического импортирования - стало сложно разбивать программу на модули.

Одна из проблем отношение одни_к_одному:

```
# модуль 1
from mod1 import B

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__B = B(self)

# модуль 2
from mod2 import A

class B:
    def __init__(self, arg: A):
        self.__a = arg
```

Ну и так далее. Проблема серьёзно нарастает с увеличением количества модулей.

Хочу узнать это я к задаче подхожу неверно, или есть решение проблемы?

ПС: я в том смысле, что возбуждается исключение ImportError, и я не могу от него избавиться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) рекомендует использовать `import module` вместо `from module import Type` и задавать типы в виде строк, чтобы уменьшить последствия от круговой зависимости, вызванной использованием type hints:

```
# mod1.py
import mod2

class B:
    def __init__(self, arg: 'mod2.A') -> None:
        self.__a = arg
```

```
# mod2.py
import mod1

class A:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__b = mod1.B(self)
```

В качестве альтернативы, если классы настолько тесно связаны, можно их в один модуль поместить или выполнить другой подходящий случаю refactoring (возможно более общий тип, определённый, к примеру, в `mod2.types`,  следует использовать в `B`). See [Type hinting would generate a lot of import statements (possibly leading to circular imports). Use strings instead of imported names?](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/105)

Comment: В виде строк нет смысла задавать типы. В этом случае подсказки работать не будут, по сути это равносильно обычному комментированию.

Comment: **import module** или **from module import name**, чаще всего тоже роли не сыграет, так как имена ещё не определены.

Comment: В один модуль - это конечно решение проблемы с импортами, но не решение задачи, так как всё-таки разбивать код на модули всегда важно.

Comment: @МистерФикс: 1- проверка типов работает и со строками, например, `B(object())` приводит: `Argument 1 to "B" has incompatible type "object"; expected "A"` Если ваше IDE не понимает типы, заданные в строках, то возможно вы используете устаревшую версию. Предложение об использовании строк в данном случае было добавлено в PEP 384 создателем языка Питона (он, кстати, также является адвокатом введения type hints в Питон) 2- `import m` vs. `from m import n` безусловно имеет значение (c `from m import n` вы просто получите ImportError) -- вы бы хотя бы код попробовали прежде чем комментировать.

Comment: Ну всё правильно. Ты импортируешь нужное имя, а потом указываешь его в подсказке. Даже если оно будет указываться внутри строки, его всё равно есть необходимость импортировать.

Comment: @МистерФикс: неверно. Основное отличие как раз, что импортируется *модуль*, содержащий имя типа, а не само *имя типа* напрямую. В одном случае у вас нет `ImportError` ошибки, а в другом  легко её получить из-за круговой зависимости.

Comment: Посидел, подумал, решил, что всё верно сказано. Скорее всего я сам упустил какие-то зависимости, когда рефакторил. Что касается типизации, то такого решения действительно достаточно, в большинстве случаев.

Answer (score 0):

```
def modCreator():
    print('''
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        from mod1 import B
        self._B = B(self)''',
          file=open('mod2.py', 'w'))

    print('''
from mod2 import A
class B:
    def __init__(self, arg: A):
        self._a = arg''',
          file=open('mod1.py', 'w'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modCreator()
    from mod1 import B
    from mod2 import A

    a = A()
    b = B(A)

    print(a, a._B)
    print(b, b._a)
```

out:

```
<mod2.A object at 0x01121ED0> <mod1.B object at 0x01121EB0>
<mod1.B object at 0x01121F30> <class 'mod2.A'>
```

Comment: Это что такое???

Comment: это решение проблемы перекрестных ссылок в вашем примере

Comment: Ну не совсем. Хотя, возможно что и единственное. Других решений точно нет?

Comment: Зачем было выводить в файлы через принты? Зачем вообще было выводить в файлы, почему нельзя было просто код написать?

Comment: а зачем столько вопросов? и да, другие решения точно есть

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, столько вопросов - потому что в текущем виде это не похоже на рабочее решение, которое стоит использовать.

Comment: одно из решений - локальный импорт. А уж использовать его или нет выбор каждого)  А принты нужны, тк автор не удосужился написать реальный пример для разбора и приходится создавать и импортировать в __main__ модули вручную

Answer (score 0):

```
def modCreate():
    modules = {}

    modules['A.py'] = '''
from G import glob
class A:
    def __init__(self, x: glob.B):
        self.x = x
        self.B = glob.B(self)
glob.A = A
'''

    modules['B.py'] = '''
from G import glob
class B:
    def __init__(self, x: glob.A):
        self.x = x
glob.B = B
    '''

    modules['G.py'] = '''
class Glob:
    def __getattr__(self, class_: object):
        print('skip %s' % class_)
glob = Glob()
    '''

    for module, code in modules.items():
        print(code, file=open(module, 'w'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    modCreate()
    from B import B
    from A import A

    from G import glob
    print(glob, [[c, getattr(glob, c)] for c in dir(glob) if not c.startswith('_')])

    a = A(B)
    print(a, a.x, a.B)

    b = B(A)
    print(b, b.x)

    print(A == glob.A)
```

out:

```
skip A
<G.Glob object at 0x02ACDE10> [['A', <class 'A.A'>], ['B', <class 'B.B'>]]
<A.A object at 0x02AA1F10> <class 'B.B'> <B.B object at 0x02AA1A50>
<B.B object at 0x02AA1F90> <class 'A.A'>
True
```

Comment: В принципе - это конечно финт. Очень любопытный финт. Но не уверен, что есть смысл на практике так делать, так как может код путать. Локальные импорты мне уже кажутся меньшим злом.

Comment: Отмечать, что ответ правильный или нет?

Comment: @МистерФикс, отмечать имеет смысл если ответ вам подходит. Если не уверены, то стоит подождать другого ответа.